# WCF service deployment issue on windows azure platform (Staging)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, azure, windows

I have created a simple WCF service which has one method which is returning a string.
I have deployed it on microsoft windows azure plateform using this [Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651130.aspx)

The management portal is saying that your service is ready. But when i paste the url of my service like http://8278a0c94dfe4b6b8159a8e1bf8.....cloudapp.net/.svc . it is giving me the following error page...

[image: Error]
Please help me in that...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the port correct for your service (e.g. 80 vs. 8080)? Are you sure the URL is correct (likely something like http://8278a0c94dfe4b6b8159a8e1bf8.cloudapp.net/Service.svc)?

Comment: i think the port is 80 and i didn't put all the character after 8e1bf8 by my self... Do i need to change the port...

Comment: You can verify the port by look at your input endpoints in your ServiceDefinition.csdef file.